# Inexplicable InDesign colour mismatch

Tags: adobe

I have two objects in InDesign.  When they are 'filled' with the same colour at 100% opacity they are the same.  But when I make them both 30% opacity they are very different.  What other variables could be controlling the colour please?

Comment: How different is "very different"? Examples would help - & also help to establish if your profiling is anything like close, if you tell us what numbers you see both there & after posting here.

Comment: Both objects are filled with color c=0, y=100, m=100, k=0.  At 100% opacity they are identical.  When I put both at 30% opacity one is very similar to the 100% version while the other has much more 'yellow' in it.

Comment: Can I post images on this site?

Comment: Yes, though it may not let you inline them - someone else can do that for you afterwards.